# AS3 switching between buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, button, switch-statement

I am trying to let the user click a button and that button determines which "tool" he/she is using. There will be multiple buttons and I need to distinguish the difference between them. For example, the user clicks the first button for one tool, then clicks the second button for the second tool. I thought I had it down, but i'm missing something. Here is what I have

```
function mMove(MouseEvent): void 
{
    if (mouseHolding && mouseY > 85 && mouseX < 610) 
    {
        clearTemp();
        switch (currentTool) 
        {
            case thisTool:
            temporaryDrawing.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            break;
        }

    thisTool.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeMode);

function changeMode(evt: MouseEvent): void 
{
   var button: Button = evt.target as Button; 
   currentTool = evt.currentTarget; // I get an error on this line.
}
```

Can I have some guidance on what i'm doing wrong, thanks :D

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting past the syntax error on your `function mMove(MouseEvent):void {` line but I'll ignore that. The best guess I can make from just the info you've given is that you're trying to downcast `evt.currentTarget` which is of type `Object`, to whatever the type of `currentTool` is.

Comment: Okay well i'm having trouble understanding what you mean. I'll provide some extra info though. At first, I had it working but instead of using "buttons" I used RadioButtons. `var Radio : RadioButton = evt.target as RadioButton;  currentTool = evt.currentTarget.label` was the original code and it worked fine --

Comment: And also may I ask what the syntax error is? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Um sorry, I didn't know you could specify a function parameter without providing a variable name. Forget what I said about the syntax error. What is the type of `currentTool`?

Comment: Hm sorry, I am fairly new to AS3 and I don't understand what a "type" would mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: @user341826 A type is what kind of variable it is. `var awd:MovieClip` The MovieClip class would be the type of `awd`. You have `var Radio:RadioButton` RadioButton is the type. You should have something similar for `currentTool`.

Comment: It would be a button, which is why I used the Button type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own question :) I just needed to figure out a way to set which button is active by creating separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your mMove is missing a closing brace. Could that be the problem?

Comment: If there is a brace missing it is a copy/paste error;